# Authentication to Azure AD using OpenID Connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I have an MVC application that authenticates the user and gets an access token for Graph API. The application was working without problems. Now, when the application is deployed to Azure websites, the application has different settings than what's configured in the code. When running locally, it continues to run without problems, reflecting the expected configuration.

The configuration I have is the following:

```
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId +"/v2.0";
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string scopes = "openid profile offline_access";
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    Scope = scopes,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                        RoleClaimType = "roles"
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync,
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                            // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                            // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

When navigating to website hosted on azure websites I get the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantid}/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri={mywebsite}%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback
&client_id={myclientid}
&scope=openid+profile+email
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=8e30e3673b7743cfb0d3bbcfc09071fe_20210506154851
&state=redir%3D%252F&sso_reload=true
```

Notice how the `response_type` (second line) and `scope` (fifth line) are different than what is configured.

When running locally, however, I get the correct settings:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={myclientid}
&response_mode=form_post
&response_type=code+id_token
&scope=openid+profile+offline_access
&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dAEBM2yvxZTbQSs_KkD_NYaV2UG0NOUz26xyvse0tCqlrBt19AEdzRRtvB8XOyHyLnP5JNg3XsYChXxzYjXOp783oLQ27Cq6Ex2MbgMsI_Fz-hGlI7T0pOGKfCZmd9tsE
&nonce=637558966120041797.ZWJlMmUxZTktZDkzNi00NjUyLTk4ZTctZDNhYzliNjkyMDExZjEyNWExNDYtMjNlZi00OTJiLWEyY2MtNzE2YTExNmIxNmJh
&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a49480%2f
&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a49480%2f
&sso_reload=true
```

Can anyone help me find why is this happening? I need the `response_type` to be `code id_token` so I can get an access token using the authorization code.

Comment: Hi, I tried this [sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/) and publish it to app service, it worked. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JcJq.png. Have you checked your code in app service? Is it the same as your local?

Comment: Hi, I tried to deploy the sample on my web service but got the same wrong configuration back, so I deployed the sample on a new web service and it worked fine then I deployed my app on the new web service and worked as well. I don't know where the problem was in my web service but at least I got things working now, thanks. @PamelaPeng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your old web service was broken, so the code could not be deployed well. If you want the reason, it's better to contact azure supporter.

Sample with OpenID Connect using ASP.NET: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/

**Startup.cs:**

```
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    string clientId = "ClientId";

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    string redirectUri = "RedirectUri";

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. tenant-id, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = "Tenant";

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant +"/v2.0");

    ......
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile, // "openid profile"
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken, // "code id_token"
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
        }
    });
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work